# Swift3 doesn't recognise an extended version of NSString from an Obj-C static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, nsstring

I have an Objective-C static library.

In this library I have an extension for `NSString (Additions)`, where I add a function called `(int) indexOf: (NSString*) text`, which returns an integer or -1 in case of an issue.

There is a Class in my library Foo.m like this:

```
#import "NSString+Additions.h"

@implementation Foo{

- (void) bar{
    NSString aString = "abcdefg";
    int anInt = [aString indexOf];
}
```

This all works fine when using the library in Objective-C.

If I use the compiled `ObjCStaticLib.framework` of this static library in a SWIFT application, the application crashes when calling `int anInt = [aString indexOf];` with this exception: `reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString indexOf:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

What I believe is happening is that for some reason instead of using my extended NSString, it is using a native one that doesn't have my function.

I have tried importing the `#import "NSString+Additions.h"` in my Bridging-Header, but the error persists.

Has anyone encountered this before? Can someone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Objective-C header-bridging

Comment: Listen to good 'ol To-ma-toes. add the header in bridging file.

Comment: Hello, like I have already mentioned I have already added the header in my Bridging file. The problem still persists.